# import cv2 returns error in jupyter notebook with python 3.6

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.6, permission-denied

I need to download opencv to run a project that requires python 3.6 and opencv. I have downloaded opencv.

I know my error is similar to [OpenCV giving an error whenever import cv2 is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254766/opencv-giving-an-error-whenever-import-cv2-is-used) but I have tried both of the solutions mentioned in that question and neither works for me.

```
!pip install opencv-python

Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.4.2.16)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in /Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.3)
```

but when i typed

```
import cv2
```

I got the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

~/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
  1 import importlib
  2 
----> 3 from .cv2 import *
  4 from .data import *
  5 

 ImportError: dlopen(/Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN10QBoxLayout10invalidateEv
 Referenced from: /Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui
in /Users/aa/.conda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

I also tried to use conda to install but I always got the following error:

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: failed

 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 253, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 282, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 223, in execute
    self.verify()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 46, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 200, in verify
    self.prepare()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 192, in prepare
    stp.remove_specs, stp.update_specs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 282, in _prepare
    mkdir_p(transaction_context['temp_dir'])
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/__init__.py", line 60, in mkdir_p
    makedirs(path)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda2/.condatmp'
```

Comment: Using `pip` within a conda environment is usually a bad idea.  Have you tried doing `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` within your env?

Comment: i tried but I always get permission denied error if I try using conda to install

Comment: try installing  it as an administrator.

Comment: Doing `sudo` and `conda` are not allowed usually.  `conda` can only be used without super user permissions and this is done by design.  Try changing the permissions to `anaconda2`.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/588497/sudo-conda-command-not-found.